# Using Batch to run remote PowerShell V1.0 command

Tags: powershell, scripting, batch-file, hyper-v

I am trying to gather some information from my Hyper-V hosts. I have a whole bunch of them and would like to automate this process.
I need to get the Virtual machines that are running on each host.
I would like to do this from a batch script.
When I run this command in the PowerShell V1.0 window (on the Hyper-V host) it works and gives me the information necessary:

```
get-vmmemory | select VMelementName,reservation | out-file c:\Output.txt
```

This is how i am running this from a batch script:

```
\\<RemoteMachine>\c$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command get-vmmemory >>aa.txt
```

This is the output I get

```
The term 'get-vmmemory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ & {get-vmmemory <<<< }
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-vmmemory:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why i keep getting this output?

Comment: Try this: `start "" "c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the UNC path you'll be running the PowerShell executable from the remote machine on the local computer. However, that won't gain you anything, becaus it's no different from running a PowerShell executable installed on your local computer. You won't be able to load modules installed on the remote machine like that.

What you need to do instead is install the [library providing Get-VMMemory](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/releases) on your local copmuter, import the module (as described e.g. [here](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/microsoft-hyper-v-articles/management/managing-hyper-v-from-command-line-part1.html)), and then use the cmdlet against the remote host:

```
Get-VMMemory -VM "virtual_host" -Server "hyper-v_host"
```

Or, you could move to [System Center Virtual Machine Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg610610.aspx).

Comment: This is the command that finally worked: Line written in BATCH file: C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "import-module '\\<remote_computer>c$\program files\modules\hyperv\hyperv.psd1'"; "get-vmmemory -server "<server_name>" | select VMelementname,reservation" >> outputfile.txt

Comment: How it works: I used the import command to import the hyperv.psd1 into the local powershell module, right after it has been imported i executed the get-vmmemory command, point it at what server i would like to run it against and use the select parameter to tell it what to return. Thank you all for the help. The eclectic information has been very useful in my understanding how this works and how i could potentially use it.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-VMMemory` isn't a standard/built-in cmdlet - it's part of the Hyper-V module. So you've really got two issues here:

1. If you're really running PowerShell v1.0 (the EXE lands in the 1.0 directory, but all versions are in the same place), the module probably won't even work
2. You aren't loading the module, or don't have the module available where you're running the batch file.

For #1, check the version this way:
    \c$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "write-host $psversiontable.psversion"

Aside: Why are you using a UNC path to point at the C drive of the local machine?

For #2, you will need to wrap your code in a PS1 file and tell powershell.exe to execute that, so that you can import the module. PowerShell 3.0 does automatic module loading, but I don't know if it will do it when you're executing the cmdlet like this.

```
import-module Hyper-V
get-vmmemory | select VMelementName,reservation | out-file c:\Output.txt
```

`powershell.exe -f myscript.ps1`

Edit: Based upon your comments, neither of these will work. You need to use PSRemoting to execute the command on the remote system, from your system.

```
invoke-command -computername hypervhost -scriptblock {get-vmmemory | select VMelementName,reservation
```

The above is untested. If this doesn't work, you will need to set up PSRemoting in your environment.

Comment: I am using UNC because this script is meant to be run from any Admin's machine. The UNC points to the PowerShell location on any of the HV servers.

Comment: I have tried the following as well: \\<remote_computer>\c$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned"

Comment: and also: \\<remote_computer>\c$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "import-module '\\SECAABHV03\c$\program files\modules\hyperv\hyperv.psd1'"; "get-vmmemory" >>aa.txt

Comment: The last one returns the following message: Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace 
At \\<remote_computer>\c$\program files\modules\hyperv\VM.ps1:73 char:26
+             Get-WmiObject <<<<  -computername $Server -NameSpace $HyperVNamespace -Query $WQL | Add-Member -MemberType ALIASPROPERTY -Name "VMEleme
ntName" -Value "ElementName" -PassThru 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Comment: I checked the version and it seems that i am using powershell 2.0. Any idea on how i can get the script to output the powershell results?

Comment: You misunderstand how programs get executed. When you execute them in this way, you are telling your local computer "go find this exe on that UNC path and run it locally." *This is not what you're looking for*. If you want to execute something remotely, you need [Powershell Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706585\(v=vs.85\).aspx)

Comment: The computer that i am running this BATCH script does not have PowerShell installed. It is a windows 7 machine.

Comment: PowerShell 2.0 comes with Windows 7 - if you don't have it, someone has removed it ([Here's how to find it](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/07/how-do-i-install-powershell-on-windows-7-and-other-questions.aspx)). Without PowerShell on your workstation, this whole exercise is going absolutely nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

get-vmmemory is not a standard cmdlet. If that cmdlet is not available on the machine where you are running powershell you will get this error.

You might need to run import-module to ensure the vmware Ps module is loaded into the session.

Answer (score 0):

When i type get-vmmemory at the PowerShell V1.0 console on the machine running hyper v (not VM) the command works.